# How to sort the language detection methods

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

In a two languages Drupal 7 site, I am using the following order of language detection methods:

- URL
- Session
- User
- Browser
- Default

With this order, every time I visit the site as an anonymous user it comes in the default language.

Instead I would like to:

- display the default language in the first visit.
- if a language selection is made, display that language in the next visit

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The problem wit the "best" is that depends only on the needs of the one who's asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you are doing just fine, and don't get obsessive over this, it's ok!

the URL thing is the most important and should be always on top, I think session should be second since it can be generated via a request or parameter.

User I'm not sure since mostly users don't pay attention about their language preferences while registering on a webiste.

past these steps the rest doesn't really matter that much, but I'd put Browser the last one since it seems it can vary quite easy with plugins/extensions.